# Is it possible to change the hour value of sql to own define value?

Tags: mysql

I was using SEC_TO_TIME to convert second to (hour and second). However, my result was wrong as my result should not be divided by 24 hours. My intention was to divide the hour that was extracted from my database and not just divide by 24 only. For example, my hour in a full day may be 8 or 8.5 only. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
DAY DOUBLE,
hourinafullday DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO test (id, DAY, hourinafullday)
VALUES ('1', '8', '8'),('2', '16', '8'),('3', '8.5', '8.5'),('4', '24', '8'),('5', '4', '8'),('6', '4', '8'),('7', '4', '8') ;

SELECT * FROM test; 


SELECT CONCAT(
    FORMAT(
        FLOOR(
            SUM(
            (DAY/hourinafullday * hourinafullday *60*60) / (3600 * hourinafullday))
            ),0), 'day',
    TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            SUM(
            (DAY/hourinafullday * hourinafullday *60*60) % (3600 * hourinafullday))
            ),'%Hh:%im')) AS TotalLeaveAMonthHour FROM test;
```

My expected result should be 8day4h:00m instead of 8day12h:00m.

Comment: So you have seconds and want to have that as hours with a fractional part? Isn't that just the seconds divided by 3600? Maybe you should elaborate on what you have and what you want. You know, `CREATE TABLE` statements of the relevant tables, `INSERT INTO` statements with sample data, the result you want to see with that sample data and what query you have at the moment.

Comment: @stickybit Hi, the code was updated, my expected result should be 8day4h:00m instead of 8day12h:00m. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Beginner, Hey did my answer helped you? if not let me know, i have found an another way.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Hi, thank you for trying that for me, however, the result was still wrong, because the correct answer should be 8day4h:00m ya. Your answer show 30minute. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something below. First find the total `seconds`. Once you find the `seconds` it will be easy in general. But since you are calculating the hours per day differently, you have to create your dividend accordingly. I'm not sure whether my logic is correct for your requirement but you can change accordingly.

```
set @seconds = (select SUM(
            (DAY/hourinafullday * hourinafullday *60*60)) from test);

set @dividend = (select FLOOR(SUM((DAY/hourinafullday * hourinafullday *60*60)
                                / (3600 * hourinafullday))) 
                 from test);            

SELECT CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%H') / @dividend), 'days',
            MOD(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%H'), @dividend ), 'h:',
            TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%im:%ss')
        )
AS Result
```

OUTPUT

```
Result
______
8days4h:30m:00s
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8eda0fedbbbac88dc46fec0828791126)